# How to measure the time profile of each django test?

Tags: django, unit-testing, profiling

I'd like to measure the (wall?) time each individual test case takes to run.

I suppose wrapping the test_runner in a timeit will do the job, but before I dive down that rabbit hole perhaps there is a smarter way to do it?

This already gives me a cProfile to pore over, but nothing really jumps out as horrendously bad.  I'm thinking perhaps my time can be focused on the ones that run the longest.

```
time python -m cProfile -o keep-p4-serialize.profile manage.py test -v 3 -k --parallel 4
```

eg:

```
test_dependencies (api.tests.TestMetricClasses) ... ok (4.003s)
test_metrics (api.tests.TestMetricClasses) ... ok (8.329s)
test_parameters (api.tests.TestMetricClasses) ... ok (0.001s)
```

Answer (score 10):

**Update:**
Original post was in 2019 and it seems that the package discussed below (`django-slowtest`) is no longer maintained. As for now I don't see any maintained forks either.

--

Old question but I came across it and noticed that `django-slowtest` is not mentioned, which I think is absolutely worth mentioning. I've been using it for quite a while now and I'm very satisfied with the results. Only downside, it does not yet state that it supports Django >= 2 **officially**, but I have not encountered any issues and since it is in development only for me I feel safe using it.

- works properly in `--parallel`
- is configurable in how many slow tests you want to show after running tests
- is configurable in threshold when it should mark a tests as `slow`
- has report (export) functionality.
- still maintained as of 2019-02

https://github.com/realpython/django-slow-tests

**from docs**:
Install:

```
$ pip install django-slowtests
```

Add the following settings:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_slowtests.testrunner.DiscoverSlowestTestsRunner'
NUM_SLOW_TESTS = 10

# (Optional)
SLOW_TEST_THRESHOLD_MS = 200  # Only show tests slower than 200ms

# (Optional)
ALWAYS_GENERATE_SLOW_REPORT = False  # Generate report only when requested using --slowreport flag
```

finally, run your tests

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.413s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Ten slowest tests:
0.3597s test_detail_view_with_a_future_poll (polls.tests.PollIndexDetailTests)
0.0284s test_detail_view_with_a_past_poll (polls.tests.PollIndexDetailTests)
0.0068s test_index_view_with_a_future_poll (polls.tests.PollViewTests)
0.0047s test_index_view_with_a_past_poll (polls.tests.PollViewTests)
0.0045s test_index_view_with_two_past_polls (polls.tests.PollViewTests)
0.0041s test_index_view_with_future_poll_and_past_poll (polls.tests.PollViewTests)
0.0036s test_index_view_with_no_polls (polls.tests.PollViewTests)
0.0003s test_was_published_recently_with_future_poll (polls.tests.PollMethodTests)
0.0002s test_was_published_recently_with_recent_poll (polls.tests.PollMethodTests)
0.0002s test_was_published_recently_with_old_poll (polls.tests.PollMethodTests)
```

Answer (score 7):

This does enough to get me by (relative timings), but it does not work for tests run in parallel, and there is certainly scope to improve the accuracy of the timings.  Nonetheless:

Override the default runner via `settings.py`:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'myapp.test_runner.MyTestRunner'
```

Thence create your own test_runner `myapp/test_runner.py`:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class MyTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    test_runner = TimedTextTestRunner
```

And, in turn, override the resultclass in that:

```
from unittest.runner import TextTestRunner, TextTestResult

class TimedTextTestRunner(TextTestRunner):
    resultclass = TimedTextTestResult
```

Now the results object is not just one result but many, so we need a collection of clocks, keyed by test.  Then capture the time the test starts and print out the time elapsed when it prints the success string:

```
class TimedTextTestResult(TextTestResult):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimedTextTestResult, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.clocks = dict()

    def startTest(self, test):
        self.clocks[test] = time()
        super(TextTestResult, self).startTest(test)
        if self.showAll:
            self.stream.write(self.getDescription(test))
            self.stream.write(" ... ")
            self.stream.flush()

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        super(TextTestResult, self).addSuccess(test)
        if self.showAll:
            self.stream.writeln("ok-dokey (%.6fs)" % (time() - self.clocks[test]))
        elif self.dots:
            self.stream.write('.')
            self.stream.flush()
```

Which gave me test reports looking like this:

```
test_price_impact (api.tests.TestGroupViews) ... ok-dokey (3.123600s)
test_realised_spread (api.tests.TestGroupViews) ... ok-dokey (6.894571s)
test_sqrt_trade_value (api.tests.TestGroupViews) ... ok-dokey (0.147969s)
test_trade_count_share (api.tests.TestGroupViews) ... ok-dokey (3.124844s)
test_trade_size (api.tests.TestGroupViews) ... ok-dokey (3.134234s)
test_value_share (api.tests.TestGroupViews) ... ok-dokey (2.939364s)
```

Comment: This works great for single-threaded tests, but run with `--parallel` all tests have a crazy-short time like (0.0000001s).

Answer (score 3):

nose has a timer plugin, which records the wall time of each single test execution.

https://github.com/mahmoudimus/nose-timer/tree/master/nosetimer

Nose's coberatura xml report also shows the time spent in each test, by default.

---

For django specific issues there are a number of easy optimizations that can be made to increase run time of tests:

- Use Sqlite, if you're not using DB specific functionality
- use a md5 password hasher, (or no password hasher at all)
- disable  migrations
- remove io, isolate logic as much as possible so complex model dependencies can avoid be created

How many tests are in `test_dependencies` and `test_metrics`? What sorts of tests are in them?

Comment: Thanks mate but it's for work and they don't use nose, the db is tied to postgres, the migrations are critical for testing, and those numbers were fabricated to provide an example.  But, hey, certainly better than no response from anyone.  I do appreciate the effort.